# SERVICENOW - Setting Approval at sc_request instead of sc_req_item

Tags: servicenow

I'm trying to set approvals at the sc_request level instead of sc_req_item.  At a high level I understand I just create a workflow that triggers on the sc_request table but all examples I've seen are evaluating if approval is needed based on price.  We don't care about price so much.  When creating the catalog item we'd like to specify which ones require manager approval and which ones don't.  How do you achieve this?

Brian

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-box field on the `sc_cat_item` table to indicate whether approval is required. Normally the item workflow runs, and the item workflow determines whether an approval is required for the item.

If you want the approval to occur at the `sc_request` level instead of the `sc_req_item` level, then a possible solution would to be add a field (a checkbox or a choice field) to `sc_cat_item` to indicate whether approval is required.

Now you submit a Request (`sc_request`) which contains one or more Items (`sc_req_item`). The question is:  Are any of those items flagged as requiring approval? You would need some code in the request workflow that loops through the items. For each `sc_req_item`, does the `sc_cat_item` indicate that approval is required?  If you find any, then you add an approval to the `sc_request`. If you are using the traditional workflow editor, then you would probably need to do the looping in JavaScript. With flow designer you could probably do it without writing JavaScript.

I think this approach gets sort of messy when there are multiple items in the request, which is why (in my experience) approvals are almost always done at the item level. If there are multiple items in the request which require approval, then the manager will get multiple emails for the multiple approvals. Maybe the manager does not like the multiple emails; but it allows the manager to approve and reject individual items. In practice, most requests only contain a single item, which is why, in practice, doing approvals at the item level seems to work well.